# l$this->db->like returning all rows instead of just the relevant ones

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like

I'm trying to filter rows using `$this->db->like` but it gets all the rows in db.

I tried using normal query:

Model:

```
 function getPostsByTag(){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts WHERE post_text  LIKE '%Astrix%'";
        $sql = $this->db->query($query);
        if($sql->num_rows > 0 ){
             return $sql->result();

         }

    }
```

controller:

```
 function tag(){
     if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
         $this->load->model('model_mutamba');
         $data['posts_by_tag'] =  $this->model_mutamba->getPostsByTag();

         $this->load->view("user/mutamba/tag",$data);


     }else{
       redirect("start");
    }
```

View:

```
 if("" != $posts_by_tag){

      foreach($posts_by_tag as $p){ 
       echo '<br>'.$p->post_text;

      }
}
```

If I add the `Not` clause before the `LIKE` it seems to work as it returns everything except the ones containing the `$tag`.

Any light shed will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$tag`? If it's ever empty, you are then querying `LIKE '%%'` which matches all rows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it's not empty. Even if I change it let's say: `SELECT * FROM mutamba_posts WHERE post_text LIKE '%Astrix%'";` It kind of puts the posts containing the word `Astrix` at the top of results but doesn't exclude the other irrelevant results.

Comment: If something that weird is happening, we will need to see more code for context. Please post the code relating to where the variable is set, where the statement is formed, executed, and fetched.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, I just noticed there was a pagination script, fetching items from another query which was getting everything from db. So, my `LIKE` is working, but when the scroll reaches the limit and  then it triggers another sql function.

Thanks for your quick replies anyways